# How to change default image of profile image

Tags: sharepoint-server

```
public static string GetUserProfilePictureURL(string username)
{
    string Url = string.Empty;

    SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site);
    UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
    if (upm.UserExists(username))
    {
        UserProfile profile = upm.GetUserProfile(username);
        if (profile != null)
        {
            Url = profile["PictureURL"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    //change it to the default if the user does not have an image specified
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Url))
        Url = "/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=";

    return Url;
}
```

How could i do this but using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/test/SiteAssets/imgToSetAsProfilePic.jpg", true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function (event) {  
  var imageAsArrayBuffer = xhr.response;  
  if (imageAsArrayBuffer) {         
    jQuery.ajax({
            url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/SetMyProfilePicture",
            type: "POST",
            data: imageAsArrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-length": imageAsArrayBuffer.byteLength
            },
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log(data);
                alert("profile pic set");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                alert("error");
            }
        });
  }
}; 
xhr.send(null);
```

Source - http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/11/set-userprofile-picture-using-net.html